# Is there a compact way to write the below function using ListComprehension/Lambda in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The rating for Alice's challenge is the triplet a = (a[0], a[1], a[2]), and the rating for Bob's challenge is the triplet b = (b[0], b[1], b[2]).
The task is to find their comparison points by comparing a[0] with b[0], a[1] with b[1], and a[2] with b[2].

```
If a[i] > b[i], then Alice is awarded 1 point.
If a[i] < b[i], then Bob is awarded 1 point.
If a[i] = b[i], then neither person receives a point.
```

Below is the function body:

```
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER_ARRAY.
# The function accepts following parameters:
#  1. INTEGER_ARRAY a
#  2. INTEGER_ARRAY b
#

def compareTriplets(a, b):
    # Write your code here
    c=0
    d=0
    for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
        if(a[i]>b[i]):
            c+=1
        elif(a[i]<b[i]):
            d+=1
    return array.array("i",[c,d])
```

Comment: A list comprehension is used (as its name suggests) to create lists, not to create integers...

Comment: You could do `c = sum(x > y for x, y in zip(a, b))` and the same for `d` but that will run the lists twice. Sometimes it is better to just go with an old-fashioned loop. Not everything in Python needs to be done the shortest way possible

Comment: I am not facing an issue. The solution works fine. I want to understand if I can make it more compact by using list comprehension or lambda

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo I am new to Python so needed some suggestion. It helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not sure why you're iterating with `range(0,len(a)-1)` - you are skipping the last element. It should be `range(len(a))`.

Second, it is more *"pythonic"* in these cases to use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function instead of using indexes. So you could do:

```py
def compareTriplets(alice, bob):
    alice_score = 0
    bob_score = 0
    for a, b in zip(alice, bob):
        if a > b:
            alice_score += 1
        elif a < b:
            bob_score += 1
    return array.array("i", [alice_score, bob_score])
```

If you're looking for ***shorter*** code (note that it doesn't mean better or faster code!), you could use the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```py
def compareTriplets(alice, bob):
    alice_score = sum(a > b for a, b in zip(alice, bob))
    bob_score = sum(a < b for a, b in zip(alice, bob))

    return array.array("i", [alice_score, bob_score])
```

As you can see this loops over the `zip` twice. For two tuples of three elements this is insignificant, but it is important to take in count that once you're dealing with big data, this approach is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the comprehension for ya:

```py
def compareTriplets(a, b):
    return [sum(tot) for tot in zip(*((aa > bb, aa < bb) for aa, bb in zip(a, b)))]
```